# How can I make python3 the default in Emacs 25.2.1?

Tags: python

I do have python3 on my laptop.

```
$ sudo find / -name "python3" | python3-locations.org
```

(partial list of locations)

> /usr/local/bin/python3
>
> /usr/lib/python3
>
> /usr/share/doc/python3
>
> /usr/share/lintian/overrides/python3
>
> /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/python3
>
> /usr/share/python3
>
> /usr/bin/python3
>
> /etc/python3

When I

```
$ emacs 25.2.1
C-x C-f foo.py
```

apparently I enter major mode Python

```
C-c C-p ; start interpreter
```

I get:

```
Python 2.7.15+ (default, Nov 27 2018, 23:36:35) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> python.el: native completion setup loaded
>>> 

Process Python finished
Python 2.7.15+ (default, Nov 27 2018, 23:36:35) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> python.el: native completion setup loaded
>>>
```

I expect that I need to add some expression in `.emacs.d/init.el`.
I have done some research into this, and found a recommendation to add this expression

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook #'(lambda () (setq py-python-command "python3")))
```

to that file. I restarted emecs with no errors, but I still get Python2.7.

What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

With the built-in python.el, you can customize `python-shell-interpreter`:

```
(setq python-shell-interpreter "python3")
```

Comment: Kyle, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Default Python-shell delivered by python-mode.el is called by <kbd>\C-c !</kbd> resp. <kbd>[(control c)(!)]</kbd>.

The key used called `run-python` from shipped python.el.

WRT to hook: it should work but only from a buffer in
python-mode. When just opening a shell, it might not be run yet and
the value not known.

Suggest to set `py-python-command` by M-x customize-variable... or using simply (setq
...)

If not done, please consider to file a bug-report at
https://gitlab.com/python-mode-devs/python-mode/issues

Comment: Andreas, thanks.

Comment: I havew solved this, with help.  Thank you.